# How to work with system menu of a window in wxWidgets?

Tags: c++, winapi, wxwidgets

I have implemented a custom titlebar for my window and I want to display the default system (context) menu when right-clicking on it. My current approach is as follows:

```
auto sysMenu = ctrl_->MSWGetSystemMenu();
if( sysMenu )
{
  //sysMenu->Bind( wxEVT_MENU, &WxWindow::onSystemMenu, this );
  ctrl_->PopupMenu( sysMenu, pos );
}
```

[image: system menu]

It successfully displays the system menu, but clicking on any item doesn't seem to have any effect. I initially thought it would send a relevant message, such as `SC_CLOSE`, to the window's message handler, but it's not happening. My second assumption was that I might need to create my own handler and handle the message there. So, I created a handler function named `onSystemMenu` like below:

```
void onSystemMenu( wxCommandEvent& e )
{
  int id = e.GetId();

  switch( id )
  {
    case wxID_MAXIMIZE_FRAME: // Maximize the window
      ctrl_->Maximize();
      break;

    case wxID_RESTORE_FRAME: // Restore the window to its previous size and position
      ctrl_->Restore();
      break;

    case wxID_ICONIZE_FRAME: // Minimize the window
      ctrl_->Iconize();
      break;

    case wxID_CLOSE_FRAME: // Close the window
      ctrl_->Close();
      break;

  }
}
```

However, the received ID is always different from those expected values. For instance, I'm receiving values like `-4048`, which doesn't correspond to any of the IDs I listed. I still believe there should be a way to achieve this without manually creating a handler. Can someone please provide assistance?

Comment: is there a reason you want this? Do you think it will be portable? Anyway - if you want it that bad, you should make your own menu with its own IDs and handle it this way. Don't rely on the system menu... BTW - if you really want this - why did you choose wxWidgets? Why not use Qt?

Comment: Well I want it becuase our users expect to see it on mouse right click. I know that it's not portable but currently we only support Windows. If I could not find a way to work with the system menu, then I have to write my own menu.

Comment: I meant why do you want a custom title bar? What purpose does it solve? As said - if you need such functionality - you should be looking at Qt... ;-)

Comment: Or better yet use some other(better suited) language for front end.

Comment: @user12002570, what kind of language are you talking about?

Comment: @user12002570 This is a completely useless comment, this has nothing to do with the language used whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the following code works:

```
    auto pos = wxGetMousePosition();
    auto hwnd = ctrl_->GetHandle();
    auto menu = GetSystemMenu( hwnd, FALSE );
    if( menu )
    {
      MENUITEMINFO mInfo;
      mInfo.cbSize = sizeof( MENUITEMINFO );
      mInfo.fMask = MIIM_STATE;
      mInfo.fType = 0;

      // update the options
      mInfo.fState = MF_ENABLED;
      SetMenuItemInfo( menu, SC_RESTORE, FALSE, &mInfo );
      SetMenuItemInfo( menu, SC_SIZE, FALSE, &mInfo );
      SetMenuItemInfo( menu, SC_MOVE, FALSE, &mInfo );
      SetMenuItemInfo( menu, SC_MAXIMIZE, FALSE, &mInfo );
      SetMenuItemInfo( menu, SC_MINIMIZE, FALSE, &mInfo );

      mInfo.fState = MF_GRAYED;

      WINDOWPLACEMENT wp;
      GetWindowPlacement( hwnd, &wp );

      switch( wp.showCmd )
      {
        case SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED:
          SetMenuItemInfo( menu, SC_SIZE, FALSE, &mInfo );
          SetMenuItemInfo( menu, SC_MOVE, FALSE, &mInfo );
          SetMenuItemInfo( menu, SC_MAXIMIZE, FALSE, &mInfo );
          SetMenuDefaultItem( menu, SC_CLOSE, FALSE );
          break;
        case SW_SHOWMINIMIZED:
          SetMenuItemInfo( menu, SC_MINIMIZE, FALSE, &mInfo );
          SetMenuDefaultItem( menu, SC_RESTORE, FALSE );
          break;
        case SW_SHOWNORMAL:
          SetMenuItemInfo( menu, SC_RESTORE, FALSE, &mInfo );
          SetMenuDefaultItem( menu, SC_CLOSE, FALSE );
          break;
      }

      auto Selected = TrackPopupMenu(
        menu, TPM_RIGHTBUTTON | TPM_RETURNCMD, pos.x, pos.y, 0, hwnd, NULL );
      if( Selected )
        SendMessage( hwnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, Selected, 0 );
    }
```

Maybe a bug in `PopupMenu` of wxWidgets?!

Comment: There is no bug here, AFAICS. When you write MSW-specific code, you need to use MSW-specific APIs. `PopupMenu()` works with `wxMenu`, not the system menu. It's perfectly fine to extend wx applications with platform-specific code but you can't expect wx API to provide support for it.